# Is it self plagirism if i use the same assignent twice in the same course?

Tags: ethics

The final essay of my course is asking a question I extensively answered in an essay earlier in the same course. Rather than doing essentially the same assignment twice. Is it wrong to edit and expand on my previous assignment and hand that in?

Comment: You should probably ask your professor this question, and see what they suggest.

Answer (score 5):

The more important question is whether this would be accepted by your professor. If you cite the earlier work it isn't plagiarism and you put the professor on notice about what you've done. But it would be much better (safer) to get permission first.

Whether it is technically self plagiarism or not depends a bit on whether you have, in some sense, *published* the earlier work. Probably you have, just by giving it to your professor. But even if it doesn't meet the technical definition, the professor could still penalize you for it.

And it isn't just the issue of copy/paste of the same words. Even paraphrasing without citation is considered plagiarism if the definition applies.

I'd guess the professor is already aware of the situation and will have a ready answer for you. They may want you to go deeper into the subject than in the first assignment.

Comment: I do not think the concept of "published" is relevant here. What's relevant is whether the learning outcomes are met if the student has already done the exercise elsewhere, or it is supposed to be some work providing skill *in addition* to previously existing skill proven with the previous iteration of the work. I agree with the "ask the professor" advice, though.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, if I write something and keep it for myself, maybe share it privately with a few friends, but don't publish it in any way, there is no issue about self plagiarism if I just copy it later in to something that I do publish. Some sort of "publishing" is needed or else there is nothing to cite. So, the question becomes "What constitutes publishing?". As I suggest here, it has probably been "published" when used to fulfill an assignment. Quite different from just finding it unused in my desk drawer.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, you can plagiarize the unpublished work of another person, but you can only self-plagiarize your published work. But the definition of "publish" can be situation dependent.

Comment: Of course, if it has never been used before, the student is free to use it. What I meant by "done the exercise" was to achieve a grade, corresponding to your use of the word "published".

Comment: I was not at all thinking of plagiarising here, of course. I find the term "self-plagiarising" also quite misleading, as strictly spoken it is not misappropriation of credit, but selling goods twice.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs, the question explicitly asks about self plagiarism.

Comment: My original comment did not refer to the term "self-plagiarism". You brought it up in your comment response to mine. I know that the term is used in the aforementioned meaning. Basically, all I am trying to say is that whether or not it is legitimate to recycle one's exercise depends on what the prof considers essential: 1. the ability to carry out the task (whether the ability is newly acquired or already established) or 2. being able to do a new task or carry out a known task in a new way.